# How do i refresh RecyclerView with SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to refresh my Recycler View, i receive my data by viewModel and pass it for my adapter
so i don’t know how to clear this data and call it again

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val viewModel: ContatoViewModel = ContatoViewModel()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    configuraObserver()
    
    viewModel.search()
}

private fun configuraObserver() {
    viewModel.contato.observe(this, { data ->
        Log.i("API", "Data received")
        contato_recyclerview.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            adapter = ContatoAdapter(this.context, data.conteudoResposta)
        }
    })
}
```

My Adapter:

```
class ContatoAdapter(private val context: Context?, private val contatos : List<Contato>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_contato,parent, false)
    return ContatoViewHolder(view)
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder as ContatoViewHolder
    val contato = contatos.elementAt(position)
    holder.bindView(contato)

}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return contatos.size
}
```

Comment: In your class there is no swipe refreshlayout. Is it to be added yet or you have shared incomplete code?

Comment: Sorry for late response, yeh there is on my xml files. Already sove the problem with notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to refresh your data(which you already received) in the recycler view you just need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from your Adapter.

SwipeRefreshLayout is needed when you want to implement pull to refresh, which means you want to trigger the initiation of API call when someone pulls down the screen and then after receiving the data you will pass it to Adapter and `notifyDataSetChanged()`

For implementing pull to refresh you can follow this [Google Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html)

Comment: Thank you, i will read this google doc, refresh the data from api is what i need